# Delayed job jobs not executing

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, delayed-job

I'm working with delayed job for the first time and I am not having any luck getting it to work and I don't understand why.  The job gets queued, but never executes.  It does get removed from the database though, so the worker seems to be processing it, but it doesn't ever run the perform method it seems.

I've set up the following initalizer:

```
require 'delayed/worker'
Dir.glob("./app/jobs/*.rb").each { |f| require f }

Delayed::Worker.logger = ActiveSupport::BufferedLogger.new("log/dj.log", Rails.logger.level)
module Delayed
  class Worker
    def self.dj_say(text)
      self.logger.info "#{Time.now.strftime('%F %T %z')}: #{text}" 
    end
  end
end
```

The initializer works, and dj.log does get written to when the work starts/exits.

My job consists of the following:

```
class UpdateServices
  attr_accessor :options
  def initialize(options)
    self.options = options
  end

  def perform
    #Debugging code
    Delayed::Worker.dj_say "starting"
    File.open("tmp/test.txt","w").close
    #End debugging code
    #bunch-o-code-here
    Delayed::Worker.dj_say "completed"
  end
end
```

None of this code ever runs.  I've tried adding debugging code into the perform method, and it never gets executed, so there is definitely something going on.  I call the job from a model like this:

```
class Service < ActiveRecord::Base
  def start_updating!(options)
    Delayed::Job.enqueue(UpdateServices.new(options), :priority => 0, :run_at => 30.seconds.from_now, :queue => 'update_services')
  end
end
```

That model is called from my controller like this:

```
Service.new.start_updating!(params)
```

My only guess is that I'm called Delayed::Job.enqueue incorrectly, but this seems to be how it should be done based on everything I've read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible for this to happen if DJ can't deserialize a job for whatever reason since the worker will force the job to permafail. This appears not to be logged by default. Try disabling failed job deletion Delayed::Worker.destroy_failed_jobs = false and seeing if there's an error.

Comment: It doesn't work any more or less than it does without the queue specified.  I am not limiting the queues.  The worker, for testing purposes is started with `bundle exec rake jobs:work`.  All the log shows is 1 line for when the worker starts, and 1 when it stops.  Nothing inbetween.

Comment: Try your rails log for the ActiveRecord queries. Can you see DJ polling? Also, is the job still in the database?

Comment: Delayed job is definitely polling, here is the log snippet: https://gist.github.com/fb05ccb37abd42c08801.  The job is removed from the database after it "runs", but the code is never executed.  Its like DJ is looking at the job and then ignoring it.

Comment: It's possible for this to happen if DJ can't deserialize a job for whatever reason since the worker will force the job to permafail. This appears not to be logged by default. Try disabling failed job deletion `Delayed::Worker.destroy_failed_jobs = false` and seeing if there's an error.

Comment: That showed me the error.  It's getting an unintialized constant error for a gem that should be working.  Is there a right or wrong way to load gems in a job?  I thought it was loaded from the bundle when the worker started, but it doesn't appear to be so.  I've also tried to `require` it in the job itself, still gives the same error.

Comment: Are your job classes in the autoload path or in /lib? If they're in lib then they're not getting loaded themselves and you should require them in an initializer which should them pick up the require you added for the gem.